# How to return an anonymous function in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code in my node project.

```
import Joi from 'joi';

module.exports = function() {
    Joi.objectId = require('joi-objectid')(Joi);
}
```

When I try to

```
export default function() {
```

it doesn't work. How can I export this function using export rather than using es5 module.exports?

Comment: What exactly is the error message? `export default function` *should* work, where `export` is available, I think

Comment: You can export default  anonymus function [Read this](https://medium.com/@poksme/you-can-export-as-default-an-anonymous-function-just-like-you-would-do-with-an-object-4d00e626ef7d) and than import with whatever name you want

Answer (score 0):

Give it a name or assign it to a variable:

```
export default function myFunc() {...}
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference? I don't *think* a function having a name affects import/export syntax, or at least, it never has in what I've worked with

Comment: @Shubham Assuming it's exported with `export default`, you'd give it a name where it's imported, eg `import changeJoiObjectId from './changeJoiObjectId'`. If one wanted to use named exports, then `import { changeJoiObjectId } ...` instead, but perhaps OP's environment just doesn't understand the `export` keyword, it's not very clear what exactly the issue is ATM

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
import Joi from 'joi';       
  const myFunc = () => {
    Joi.objectId = require('joi-objectid')(Joi);
  }
export default myFunc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your environment is "nodejs", you probably are not using any transpilers. This mean you have to follow nodejs extensions to allow es6 modules.

To enable es6 modules, you first need to change the extension of your script to `mjs`, then start nodejs using `node --experimental-modules index.mjs`

See also https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html